# Django project deployment on an offline pc, locally, we don't want to go online

Tags: django, iis, reverse-proxy, django-deployment

I have a Django project. we cannot go online, is there any way to deploy the project in a client computer just for the client to use there on his pc? no need to go online! user needs to type an address in browser to get the starting page of some other easy path! is it possible? or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a long term plan ? Like a production app but located only on the user pc ?

Comment: yes it is, a production app but on the user pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To temporarily run the code to demonstrate the project to the client locally on their computer you should utilize pipenv to install the packages on their computer. You can then run the Django server using `python manage.py runserver` as normal without effecting their computer. Be sure to replace `python` with the location of the virtual python environment.

If this is something they will be using locally long-term, you can always create a script which launches the Django server on boot-up and create a shortcut to the site on their desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I create a cmd shortcut in desktop running the command "python manage.py runserver" in the project folders path. and it works.

Comment: Did you install python and all requirements on clients pc? Did we have to share our Django project to client pc?